# What would be the best way to select drawn Bezier curve?

Tags: c#, bezier

I'm working on a graphical program. I'm wondering what would be the best way to get focus on a drawn bezier curve. Untill now, I've got ellipses and rectangles implemented and it's easy to focus/select them (you need to click inside of it only). What would be the best way to add it to drawn curves? I want to make 4 rectangles appear near bezier curve as soon as this curve gets selected but I'm not sure how to detect this curve's selection.
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid, that without knowing the details of you implementation its difficult to help, how are you drawing them? can you obtain at any moment the x and y of the entire curve?

Comment: well, my curve is made out of 4 points, so i can easily draw it with Graphics.DrawBezier(Pen, p1, p2, p3, p4), I have got them saved ofcourse

Comment: OH ok, when I was studying in one class we create a 2D api, (in java) so, we created a plane and we could draw in it, we could zoom in and out, transpose and rotate and everything, we had a method that converted points in the plane (x,y) to the position in the canvas we were painting, it had a great level of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw your bezier curve using a System.Windows.Shapes.Path() you can just use standard UI events like

```
myPath.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(myPath_MouseEnter);
```

etc.

Comment: I'm making it in a windows forms and Id like to avoid adding WPF classes.